# Link_to method keeps redirecting back to root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, path

Why does this link_to method redirect to my root path?

Users controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.comments.build
  @comment = Comment.new
  @user.votes.build
  @vote = Vote.new
end

def vote:
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  Vote.create!(voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Comments')
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to @user
end
```

Users view:

```
<%= link_to "vote", vote_comment_path(:id => comment.id), method: :post, :class=> "btn %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
post 'comments/:id/vote' => 'comments#vote', as: 'vote_comment'
resources :users do
  resources :comments
  resources :ratings
    resources :votes
  end
```

I was expecting clicking on vote to redirect back to the user, but instead it goes to my home page.

Can I not use `params[:id]` twice under the same method?

Comment: could you provide UsersController#show code?

Comment: Show your routes file.

Comment: Try to change `redirect_to @user` to `redirect_to user_path(@user)`

Comment: @emaxi Added it above.

Comment: @Substantial Added them above.

Comment: @PavelTkackenko That code still redirects to the root path.

Comment: Is that vote method above `comments#vote` or `users#vote`?

Comment: @Substantial Comments#vote, but it's on the Users show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
vote_comment_path(:id => comment.id)
```

it passes `comment.id` into the method, which is retrieved as `params[:id]`.

If the value of `params[:id]` is `comment.id`, then:

```
def vote
  # ... 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  # look up user by comment.id - BAD!
  redirect_to @user               # wrong user!
end
```

You are looking up a user by a comment ID, not a user ID.

If the current user is **User 1** but the comment is **Comment 5**, you are being redirected to **User 5**, the user with the same ID as the comment.

I'm guessing there is some authorization check dumping you back to root (eg. not allowed to view **User 5** while logged in as **User 1**). Check your logs to see where the redirect took place.

---

This might be related, but the proper way to build is like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @user.comments.build
  @vote = @user.votes.build
end
```

Comment: Ah I see. How would you suggest I redirect to the current user?

Comment: `redirect_to current_user`